# Highcharts: Position tooltip above the bar on a bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Working with highcharts and I'm attempting to get the tooltip on a bar chart to hover directly above the right hand side of the bar. For example:

[image]

Currently I'm using the positioner function but I can't seem to figure out the math to get this to work. Currently when I attempt to use the point.plotX and point.plotY options the tooltip hovers in what appears to be a random spot, and I'm unable to find where you would get the right hand position of the bar. Here's the code I'm currently using

```
positioner: function(width, height, point) {
   return {
     x: point.plotX,
     y: point.plotY,
   };
},
```

and here's the output for how that looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a typo in your `positioner` function. You should use `plotY` insted of `ploty` property:

```
tooltip: {
    positioner: function(width, height, point) {
        return {
            x: point.plotX,
            y: point.plotY,
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/poxv4wq1/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

**EDIT:**

The positioner function return a tooltip coordinates relative to the entire chart. The values `point.plotX` and `point.plotY` are relative to the plot area, so you need to add `chart.plotTop` and `chart.plotLeft` values:

```
    positioner: function(width, height, point) {
        var columnWidth = this.chart.series[0].options.pointWidth;

        return {
            x: point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft,
            y: point.plotY - columnWidth / 2 + this.chart.plotTop - height
        };
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0cjftrsy/

Comment: Fixing the type is still giving me the issue of having the tooltip positioned what appears randomly to the left of the edge. Could this be because of the large width to my y-axis labels? I've edited the original code / image in my question.

Comment: Hi Tim McGee, Could you reproduce this situation in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fqbkozpr/1/ this fiddle shows the behavior. Interestingly if you remove the y-axis label formatter (thus removing the extra width of the label) the positioner function works properly.

Comment: @Tim McGee, Thanks fot the example. The `positioner` function return a tooltip coordinates in relation to the chart, you need to add `chart.plotTop` and `chart.plotLeft`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0cjftrsy/

Answer (score 0):

ok, becouse of the label styles. The position of the toolTip is of.

This how i fixed it.

This example worked with http://jsfiddle.net/fqbkozpr/1/

```
 return {
        x: Math.max(point.plotX, width), // To the right.
        y: point.plotY + height, // Make sure to be under the line
      };
```

Comment: Its upp to you to use `Math.max(point.plotX, width)` but `point.plotY + height` is very importend